# NServiceBus 4.0.3 NHibernate schema update does not happen

Tags: nhibernate, schema, nservicebus

In NServiceBus v3.3.x when using NHibernate saga persister I used to get my DB schema updated once properties are added to entities. Now, when I moved to NServiceBus v4.0.3, it stopped working. The saga is configured with

`.UseNHibernateSagaPersister()` and `.UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()`

but no joy, the schema is not recreated. I guess the question I would like to ask would be in which cases is the schema updated?

Comment: Do you have an associated configuration section for each?  The property UpdateSchema there will control that.

Comment: @Adam The configuration sections are there for both of them and UpdateSchema is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

In NServiceBus v4 NHibernate schema updates are only done if:

- You are running in debug mode inside VS (basically the debugger is attached)
- You run the installers, eg `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install`

Comment: By debug mode I mean running from inside VS and pressing F5, is that what you are doing?